How is it possible to save the terminals layout in VSCode?
When VSCode stops promptly (for whatever reason), the terminals are not saved, and I need to re-open all the terminal by hand, which I find very cumbersome.
So there is my question: how is it possible to save the layout of the open terminals in VSCode to recover them later?

Not sure about VSCode terminal layouts but it may be worthwhile to look into tmux as an alternative. You can also write bash scripts to have predefined layouts for your projects.
PS: This video is a quick intro to what you can do with it.

Automating terminals with tasks

You can configure tasks to optimize your work, open .vscode and add a tasks.json See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 . ps once the terminal is closed, you lose all the history of that

@SannatBhasin I'm not at ease with those tool, and furthermore the question was really about vscode solution.
rioV8 and francisco: Thanks both of you for this tool I was obviously not aware of. Seems to be the solution to my problem, just need to test a bit.

As stated by rioV8 in comments, answer is to automatize terminal creation using a .vscode/tasks.json.
It's a bit off-topic, but I wanted to launch WSL terminals, and I had to tweak the code in the documentation like the following to make it work:
{
  "label": "app",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "",
  "icon": {
    "id": "bug",
    "color": "terminal.ansiCyan"
  },
  "options": {
    "shell": {          
      "executable": "C:\\windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
      "args": ["-d", "Ubuntu-24.04"]
    },
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/app"
  },
  "isBackground": true,
  "problemMatcher": [],
  "presentation": {
    "group": "app"
  }
}

Particularly, those lines are important:
"shell": {          
   "executable": "C:\\windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
   "args": ["-d", "Ubuntu-24.04"]
}

If we put wsl.exe in shell.executable, the real executed command is C:\\windows\\System32\\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-24.04 -e which expects a command after -e, which is not the case when launching a terminal only.
